# Xcode 7 crashes when trying to open .sks files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, xcode7

I know many other people are still having this problem, but I wanted to bring this up again in case anyone has found an issue and hasn't shared it yet.

Xcode 7 (7.3.1) crashes immediately with no error message when I try and open an sks file (such as a particle file or the GameScene.sks file). Does anyone know a fix? Like do I have to download and use xcode 8, does that work with sks files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like, at least for me, that xcode 8 may be required to open these files. So try installing that version and it should work.